# Which iOS Reachability class would you use?

Tags: ios, networking

How does the Apple Reachability class compare to this [3rd party reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)?  Which would you use in your project and why?  Thanks.

Comment: For a long time the reason to use 3rd-party reachability code was that the Apple project (https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) was not compatible with ARC. That has changed in the mean time, so I think it is a matter of taste which API you prefer. (They all use SCNetworkReachability under the hood.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** I prefer using [FXReachability](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXReachability) because of it's lightweight nature and extreme simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Reachability class provided by apple gives us basic idea of how reachability test will be done and how we can check for the networks.

Link you provided have the class of reachability which consist of there own customization.

So I would suggest you, it will be your decision which class fulfill your project requirement.

No one tell you which class you should use without knowing your requirement.

So better to try both and check which will give you exact thing which you want.

But if you have only basic check for Internet connection go with Apple Reachability class